# Soil moisture conditions and air temperatures - literature needed

Tags: temperature, flooding, soil-moisture

I am looking at basics academic papers which tell about the physical floods mechanisms.

In particular something that says that: 'lower temperatures reduce evapotranspiration, enhancing wet soil conditions which reduce the soil infiltration promoting water runoff and eventually fluvial peak flows'.

Do you know anything about this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're after "basic" academic work, I suggest the following 2003 textbook from the Utah State University entitled, "Rainfall Runoff Processes", chapter 2:

[Runoff Generation Mechanisms](http://hydrology.usu.edu/RRP/userdata/4/87/ch2.pdf)

It looks like a pretty good compendium of what you're looking for with easy-to-understand text and clear diagrams. Further detail, if needed, can be found by hunting down the references within. The entire textbook can be downloaded here:

[Rainfall Runoff Processes](http://hydrology.usu.edu/RRP/userdata/4/87/RainfallRunoffProcesses.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

This is generally true, but like most things in nature, there are exceptions. There is no capacity to hold additional water once soils are saturated to the surface and infiltration is limited by the generally slow rate of groundwater flow. This produces saturation-dependent overland flow and greatly increases runoff.

Another effect is that cold conditions reduce vegetation growth, especially annual grasses. The lower groundcover promotes runoff.

However, under dry conditions some soil types can become hydrophobic, which also reduces infiltration and increases runoff. [This can be due to coating of soil particles with organic substances](http://soilquality.org.au/factsheets/water-repellency) as can occur in native forests in Australia due to eucalyptus and other oils. I believe this is a bit of an over-simplification because it does not consider the unsaturated flow dynamics that could impede infiltration without organic coatings.